# Center a grid-block in a Foundation 4 Grid

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I am currently working with Zurb-Foundation 4 and I've faced a problem while trying to have a centered Block-Grid in a (small)large-12 Row.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row" id="boardcontainer">
    <div class="small-12 large-12 large-centered columns">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-3 text-center" id="board">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I always get a left aligned 3x3 grid. I just want to have this grid centered in a large-12 row. I have to mention, that my li-elements are given a fixed width and fixed height.

Is this possible using the grid-block within a large-12 row?

Update: I've created a small jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/EwOZ/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `display: inline-block` to your `ul` element, then change the width of your `li` elements to `width:98px;`.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/q7pVn/) showing it in action.

Comment: As I've overwritte the style of an <li> with a fixed width, this does not work :( It is still left aligned. Here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/EwOZ/1

Comment: Great, glad that worked for you. I'm going to edit my answer to remove the un-needed part.

Comment: @casarock What is the point of using a grid based box system if you are going to manually set the widths?

Comment: @JM4 it's only a small part of a more complex layout. As I was using foundation for the whole Layout I thought I could use block grids for my tiled board. You are right it's not a real use case for block grids.